# How we can create the pallet extrinsic to create the multiple tokens?

Tags: pallet

I want to create a pallet by which any user can create the token on the my substrate chain.
do we have any pallet which can help in the implementation of this feature?
any reference would be appreciable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Pallet-assets](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/frame/assets/src/lib.rs) does this for you!